# Office documents in UIWebView with time difference between dates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I've been using UIWebView to render office docs for a while, but recently I noticed that when a date is added in the file, let's say an Excel file with a date value in one of the cells, the date is (apparently) being modified by the web view.

The weird thing is that I made a test based on two projects. The first one, is a project that I've been working on for about a year and the second is new one that I created just for testing purposes.

The dates are being displayed correctly in the new project, but wrong in the old project so I'm starting to think is something regarding the project settings. I also copied the classes from the new project to the old one to see if there was a difference, but even using the new classes, my old project shows incorrect(*) dates for the same excel file.... so that's weird.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

**Update 1:**
(*)By incorrect dates, I mean there is a time difference between the one displayed in the test project and the one displayed in the old project for the same file.

I changed the title of the question from "... invalid dates" to " ...time difference between" ... because the word "invalid" may lead to a misunderstanding.

Comment: Are the dates off by four years? If so, then it's a mixup between the zero date for Mac (1904) and Windows (1900). See [The 1900 Date System vs. the 1904 Date System](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162/en-us). And it would be a bug because each Excel sheet indicates which base is used.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. No, the difference is around 3 or 4 hours. And if the problem was related to date system, the problem must be present in both projects, which is not the case.

Comment: Can you modify this date? If so, there is a variable called localtime, in ctime.h. It's a C variable from the UNIX system. Maybe you can subtract the GMT time from the localtime. I had a similar problem with  another system and that corrected the problem.

Comment: Do the two projects differ at all in that one manipulates the locale, time zone, calendar, etc. in any way?

Comment: Could it be column-specific formatting in the old excel file?  Try creating a new date column on a newly created worksheet in the old excel file, and type (do not copy and paste) the date value into the new date column.  If it displays correctly, then it's just excel file column formatting (most likely a timezone offset) on the date column of the old excel file.

Comment: Thank you for all the replays folks -> to RaphaelAyres: I'm not able to modify the date since I'm only trying to display the document.-> to Carl: I don't think so, is there a setting somewhere in the project that refers to time zones? any clue will be appreciated =D ->  to tetsuo000: I've created different spreadsheets using different versions of Office (Mac and Windows) with the same results.

Comment: can you use Mac Office versions for editing the time-values on both . Just change one time-value on both the spreadsheets and check if its showing the same or not.

Comment: @VimalVenugopalan tried that, I also created new excel files but the problem is still there. Thanks for your answer anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to understand what the problem was, but the solution for now is to change the visualization component from UIWebView to the QuickLook framework.

I know this is not the correct answer to the question, but at least is a way to display the document correctly.